# Is it okay to connect two In and Out neutral cables to the same relay point?

Tags: water, heater

Bought a timer for my water heater.

It has 4 entries (2 entries each) (left to right): L-in, Lout2, Lout1 and N

I am used to having the N for each L. Does it matter if I connect both IN and OUT N to the same entry (one to each hole)?

Adding photo:
[image]

Edit #2:
I do live in Israel

Edit #3:
The manufacturer is Omega, model number OM-TIS45-B - but I have been unable to find any info online on this model.

Comment: Why don't you post make and model and link to installation manual? Don't install it if you are unsure or not legally allowed to install it. Get a professional electrician to do it.

Comment: This may depend on your local wiring regulations. I'm not going to guess where you are.

Comment: If you can find a link to online documentation for that timer that would really help. If you probe the two entries for L in, are they shorted together? Or are they independent? (I am talking about probing the entries when everything is disconnected and totally de-energized and safe).

Comment: It looks to me like it's an `Omega` brand, model OM-T1545-8. It also looks like Hebrew writing on the right side of that label. Can you confirm what I'm seeing and that you're located in Israel? That will help people address local codes (if anyone happens to know them or has enough search-fu to find Israeli code _in English_).

Comment: Definitely need to see an installation manual. The saynet.co.il web site has some information (click the US flag to see English pages) but not much. But I thought, seriously, that all water heaters in Israel were solar (or at least all installed for the last many, many years in ordinary homes).

Comment: One could, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, have a timer for a solar heater to avoid using power during certain parts of the day.

Comment: @FreeMan Solar water heater as in "sun heats water going through tubes in a box on the roof". No electricity involved.

Comment: Gotcha. Only works during the day, though...

Comment: The model is `OM-TIS45-B`, but some of the retailers list it as `OM-TIS-45B`. I found it listed for sale at just about every single Israeli electronics retailer, but none of them have the manual (in any language), and I cannot find the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Please repost your picture, but use StackExchange's own hosting instead of someone else's. That will prevent the "big blue box" error we're seeing now. Just drag your picture into the post & the site will upload and host it for you. Also, while you're [edit]ing your post, please include the manufacturer & model number info as you've been asked for.